# ansible iterate through dictionary

Tags: dictionary, ansible

How to interate through this dictionary?
If vrf is default than print proc name.
If vrf is other than defaul than print proc name and vrf name

```
 proc-vrf: [{'proc': 'T1', 'vrf': 'default'}, {'proc': 'T2', 'vrf': 'vrf_T2'},, {'proc': 'T3', 'vrf': 'default'}, {'proc': 'T3', 'vrf': 'vrf_T3'}]
```

I tried following:

```
- name: Display output...
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.key }} - {{ item.value }}"
  loop: "{{ proc-vrf | dict2items }}"
```

I am getting following error:

```
ERROR! 'item' is undefined
```

Comment: what have you tried? is it giving you any error? if so, what error? 

have you read the documentation?(https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html)

Comment: You can't name a variable `proc-vrf`; `-` is an invalid character in variable names. It also doesn't make sense to pass that variable to `dict2items` because the variable is a *list*, but `dict2items` is meant to be used with *dictionaries*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the additional information, the question looks better.

As in this case the variable is a list of dictionaries, replace the *loop:* with

```
- name: Display output...
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.proc }} - {{ item.vrf }}"
  with_items: "{{ proc_vrf }}"
```

change proc-vrf  to proc_vrf . typo

Comment: Thx but I am still getting "ERROR! 'item' is undefined" . and how to address this requirement "If vrf is default than print proc name. If vrf is other than defaul than print proc name and vrf name"

Comment: oh, the input data is inconsistent, between the second and third element there is a double comma, the loop will have issues as that element will be considered null; are you familiar with ansible-lint or yamllint? those tools are quite handy to catch those details

Comment: Just like to note that using a variable name like `proc-vrt` will result into an error `ERROR! Invalid variable name in vars specified for Play: 'proc-vrf' is not a valid variable name`.

Answer (score 0):

After addressing the variable name because of

```
ERROR! Invalid variable name in vars specified for Play: 'proc-vrf' is not a valid variable name
```

and its content

```bash
diff <( echo 'proc-vrf: [{'proc': 'T1', 'vrf': 'default'}, {'proc': 'T2', 'vrf': 'vrf_T2'},, {'proc': 'T3', 'vrf': 'default'}, {'proc': 'T3', 'vrf': 'vrf_T3'}]' ) <( echo 'proc_vrf: [{'proc': 'T1', 'vrf': 'default'}, {'proc': 'T2', 'vrf': 'vrf_T2'}, {'proc': 'T3', 'vrf': 'default'}, {'proc': 'T3', 'vrf': 'vrf_T3'}]' )
1c1
< proc-vrf: [{proc: T1, vrf: default}, {proc: T2, vrf: vrf_T2},, {proc: T3, vrf: default}, {proc: T3, vrf: vrf_T3}]
---
> proc_vrf: [{proc: T1, vrf: default}, {proc: T2, vrf: vrf_T2}, {proc: T3, vrf: default}, {proc: T3, vrf: vrf_T3}]
```

a sample playbook like

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    proc_vrf: [{'proc': 'T1', 'vrf': 'default'}, {'proc': 'T2', 'vrf': 'vrf_T2'}, {'proc': 'T3', 'vrf': 'default'}, {'proc': 'T3', 'vrf': 'vrf_T3'}]

  tasks:

  - name: Display output...
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item.proc }} - {{ item.vrf }}"
    loop: "{{ proc_vrf }}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Display output...] ****************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'proc': u'T1', u'vrf': u'default'}) =>
  msg: T1 - default
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'proc': u'T2', u'vrf': u'vrf_T2'}) =>
  msg: T2 - vrf_T2
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'proc': u'T3', u'vrf': u'default'}) =>
  msg: T3 - default
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'proc': u'T3', u'vrf': u'vrf_T3'}) =>
  msg: T3 - vrf_T3
```

**Further Documentation**

- [Creating valid variable names](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names)

  > *Not all strings are valid Ansible variable names. A variable name can only include letters, numbers, and underscores.*

Answer (score 0):

- name: Display output...
  debug:
  msg: "{{ item.proc }} - {{ item.vrf }}"
  loop: "{{ proc_vrf }}"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).